# the mail service in joomla

Tags: php, email, joomla

Hello I need help with joomla, I have a form on my page is the following
[ver formulario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4tp8.png)

When we click on send the following message:

There was an error while sending the admin email: Could not instantiate mail function.

The mail arrives that is sent, arrives at the administration of joomla, where the following warning is displayed:

This email could not be sent to correo@....

If anyone knows how to solve that problem, thanks for the help, I've read a lot and tried everything I found on the Internet. 
but I still can not solve my problem.

the version used is
Joomla 3.6.5

[Photo of global configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0dBG.png)

Comment: On global configuration/ server how is your mail server setup?

Comment: @MarceloStaudt is right, it is hard to help without knowing your current setup.

Comment: Thank you, add a photo of the global configuration in the question   
@MarceloStaudt YellowWebMonkey

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to send an email from an email account that can't be used to send emails from from your IP (yes, there are 2 froms in the previous sentence). Your from email is "learn@gmail.com" which you cannot use to send emails from your domain (unless you add the proper authentication in your configuration). Use a proper email (such as `youremail@yourdomain.com` ) or use add the gmail authentication to your configuration. We have experienced the same issue with one of our clients before, see [this post](https://www.itoctopus.com/could-not-start-mail-function-error-when-registering-on-a-joomla-website) for more information about this subject.

Comment: Thank you very much, I already achieved the problem, not in the way that indicates but still, I'm guided by the right way, I publish the answer in case it is useful to someone else:
The sending of mail is solved by adjusting the use permission of sendmail by Apache.